# How to get data from SOAP response js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, soap

I've a API that returns this data for me.

I need to access the datas inside this. I've tried some `response.SOAP-Env:Envelope` but got error because of two points.

Can't debug it more because Im using react native.

http://myjson.com/14veid

```
{
  "SOAP-ENV:Envelope": {
    "$": {
      "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/",
      "xmlns:SOAP-ENV": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
      "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
      "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
      "xmlns:SOAP-ENC": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    },
    "SOAP-ENV:Body": [
      {
        "Entidade.dadosEntidadeResponse": [
          {
            "return": [
              {
                "$": {
                  "xsi:nil": "true",
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:int"
                }
              }
            ],
            "msgResult": [
              {
                "_": "Ok",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "rsEntidade": [
              {
                "_": "ASSOCIAÃÃO PRO MELHORAMENTOS DA VILA PREL",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "enderecoEntidade": [
              {
                "_": "RUA THEREZA MAIA PINTO",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "telEntidade": [
              {
                "_": "1158126849",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "emailEntidade": [
              {
                "_": "xxx@uol.com.br",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "telPresidente": [
              {
                "_": "5222682-2716",
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ],
            "emailPresidente": [
              {
                "$": {
                  "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

}
```

I need to access the `emailEntidade`, `telEntidade` proprieties of this response.
Tried many wat to do this but without success.
Using javascript, react native

Comment: It hardly needs to be accessed using full properties of the envelope.